# Sorting array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object:

```
var Data = [{
    item_id:1,
    name:'John',
    date:1262293200000,
    votes:1
}, {
    item_id:2,
    name:'Nick',
    date:1313784000000,
    votes:2
},{ 
    item_id:3,
    name:'Paul',
    date:1299186000000,
    votes:-3
}]
```

I want to sort it by `item_id`, `name`, `date` and `votes`. **Asc** and **desc**. To do this I use this function:

```
function dynamicSort(property) { 
    return function (a,b) { 
        return (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0; }}

Array.prototype.sortBy = function(property) { return this.sort(dynamicSort(property)) }
Array.prototype.reverseBy = function(property) { return this.reverse(dynamicSort(property)) }
```

It's sorts and reverses nice, but only frow second calling. For example:

```
videoDataList.reverseBy("user_votes")
```

result will be wrong, but if I do sortBy and then again `reverseBy` it will be correct sorting.
Also if i call `reverseBy` and then `sortBy` sorting of `sortBy` will be correct.

Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reverse function for an array accepting a function as a parameter.
You should try:

```
 Array.prototype.reverseBy = function(property) {
    return this.sortBy(dynamicSort(property)).reverse()
 }
```

Comment: You are wrong. `dynamicSort(property)` is called once, its result (the sort function) is then passed as a parameter to `Array.sort()`. And that function (and only that function) is called for each comparison (btw. there are `n * log(n)` comparisons for sorting). So your optimization has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: You are right, I guess it's still too early for me to think clearly :) I'll delete this from my post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will use [jLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq)?
In jLinq sorting looks:

```
var result = jlinq.from(Data).sort("-votes").select();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) doesn't take any parameters. It doesn't sort the array, merely reverses its current order. So you could either sort the list first (note that both `Array.reverse()` and `Array.sort` modify the array in-place, without creating a new array):

```
Array.prototype.reverseBy = function(property)
{
  this.sortBy(property);
  this.reverse();
  return this;
};
```

Or you use a reverse sorting function:

```
function dynamicSortReverse(property)
{
  var innerFunc = dynamicSort(property);
  return function(a, b) { return -1 * innerFunc(a, b); };
}
Array.prototype.reverseBy = function(property) { return this.sort(dynamicSortReverse(property)); };
```

The second approach is the more efficient one.

Note that you can simplify your `dynamicSort` function if you are only sorting by numerical properties:

```
function dynamicSort(property)
{ 
  return function (a, b)
  { 
    return a[property] - b[property];
  }
}
```

This should also be slightly more efficient. Of course, if you are sometimes sorting by string values you will still need the old function.